# How to pass a component to another component in React?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I want to write a tab component like below,it's ok when I click tab1 to show the content of **test**,but when I define a class component like **test2**, it seems wrong.And the erro is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function'.Thanks so much.

```
// use of component
const tabs = [
    {tabName: 'tab1', content: () => <Tab.Pane component={test} /> },
    {tabName: 'tab2', content: () => <Tab.Pane component={test2} /> }
];

const test = () => {
    return (<HGroup>tetetetetetet</HGroup>)
};
class test2 extends Component {
    render() {
        return(<HGroup>123213</HGroup>)
    }
}

@observer
export default class EditLabels extends Component {
    render() {
      return (<Tab panes={tabs} />)
    }
}


// component 
@observer
class Tab extends Component {

@observable activeIndex = 0;

static Pane = ({children, component}) => {

    console.log(typeof component);
    return (
        <VGroup>
            {children && <HGroup>{children}</HGroup>}
            {component && component.call(this)}
        </VGroup>

    )
};

render() {
    const { panes } = this.props;
    return (
        <VGroup>
            <HGroup>{ panes.map((item, index) => {
                return (<HGroup key={index}
                                onClick={() => this.activeIndex = index}
                                style={this.activeIndex === index && {color: 'red'}}>{item.tabName}</HGroup>)
            })}
            </HGroup>

            {panes[this.activeIndex].content()}

        </VGroup>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: You don't need a function to return JSX. I usually do ```const myComp = <MyComponent />;```

Comment: It seems like, because `test2` is a class, that `{component && component.call(this)}` in Pane is what's causing it to fail. We cannot call `.call()` on a class, so a TypeError exception is thrown. Try removing the `.call()`, and just leave that line `{component}`